# `KeyError: 'Date' al importar archivos csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Dispongo del script siguiente:

```
import glob 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dirección para obtener los ficheros 
path = "/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2020/Py_Paso_Peregrino/Ficheros_Yahoo_csv/"

"""Importa los datos de los ficheros csv de una dirección determinada"""
filenames = glob.glob(path + "*.csv") 
dfs = []
nombres = []
for filename in filenames: 
    nombre = filename[len(path):-4] 
    nombres.append(nombre)    
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
dfs = iter(dfs)
df_final = next(dfs)
for df_ in dfs:
    df_final = df_final.merge(df_, on='Date')

df_final = df_final.set_index("Date")

df_final.columns = nombres

df_final[:3]
```

En los enlaces que vinculo a continuación, se encuentran ficheros .csv, descargados de Yahoo unos, y de Renta 4, otros. La diferencia entre ambos es el separador y la coma.

[https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rejquck45eqvu6b/AADCXdg0zOaUlGS_DFdtm_ita?dl=0][1]

[https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ccyhk5arg3yy3ga/AADUjycKwvyzbSmhkHsAlqLsa?dl=0][1]

Con la sentencia `pd.read_csv(filename)` lee perfectamente los archivos ubicados en "Ficheros_Yahoo_csv.

Deseo leer tambien los ubicados en "Ficheros_R4_csv, que utilizan la coma como decimal y como separador "\t". Para ello sustituyo la sentencia mencionada anteriormente por:

```
pd.read_csv(filename,  decimal  =",", sep='\t', na_values = ["nan"], parse_dates = True)
```

Al ejecutar me devuelve el error `KeyError: 'Date'`

Agradeceré vuestras sugerencias para superar este problema.

Comment: Hola efueyo, tu código es correcto, el problema es el csv llamado "ValorRelativo_ES0128522002_r4.csv", no tiene la mima estructura que el resto. Aunque se puede parsear sería un caso aparte de los otros de la carpeta.

Comment: Efectivamente, ese era el problema. Gracias

Comment: De nada. Un saludo.